# Getting formulas out of Excel

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet that I need to convert into code. Is there a way to export the spreadsheet that keeps the formulas intact?

When I save it as any other format it converts the formulas to their values. For example, if I had =(4/2), the CSV would just put 2. Whereas I need the original formula. I have tried accessing the spreadsheet using PHP Excel also but it cannot load the spreadsheet due to size.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to do CTRL+` and then copy+paste to Notepad or wherever you want

Comment: This is the correct answer. Also, when saving the spreadsheet as a CSV after pressing CTRL+` (show formulas), the formulas will be saved to the CSV file instead of the values.

Comment: This would work if you were doing it manually, but won't work as an export.